# How to find what image is displayed in UIImageView swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I'm trying to find out what image is stored in the UIImageView using swift.

I have a UIImageView with a image in which is held in a UIScrollView. When the image is tapped, it calls a function, which I have passed the UIImageView to, but I need to be able to access the image which is held inside the UIImageView.

This is how I've defined the image

```
let dogImage = UIImage(named: "dog")
```

And I'd like to get back to the that constant in the called function, but I can only figure out how to get the image view and can't access the image that is inside of it (which would be dogImage)

```
func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //this function gets called when an image is tapped

    //tappedImageView is the image view that was tapped.
    let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view!
```

How would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to the `UIImage` object like so:

```
func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  if let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view as? UIImageView {
    print(tappedImageView.image)
  }
}
```